# Why is 点 in 光学硕士点?

Tags: usage

I walk past this sign on the way to the lab:

[image]

If I understand correctly, it says something like *the optics Master's lab (?) was founded in 1984 by the supervisor Guoguang Mu.*

I'm interested in the bottom sentence:

> 光学硕士点 (guāngxué shuòshì diǎn)

Which translates to:

- [光学](http://dict.cn/%E5%85%89%E5%AD%A6) (guāngxué) = optics
- [硕士](http://dict.cn/%E7%A1%95%E5%A3%AB) (shuòshì) = Master's (as in "Master's degree" and "Master's student")
- [点](http://dict.cn/%E7%82%B9) (diǎn) = dot

I'm confused as to why 点 is in this sentence.  In context it seems to mean "lab", but I would expect other words to mean lab.

**Question**: Why is 点 in 光学硕士点?

Comment: site.   You understand it exactly.

Comment: 点 means a place or degree. like: 报名点(registry), 代售点(agency), 起点(starting point), 燃点(burning temperature), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

点 means a unit here.

This 点 is the same as the one in 地点 or 景点.

In this case, it is a place that they can confer Master's degrees.

Usually, it is a department of a university, which is also an organization (组织) or a unit (单位).

A 硕士点 is authorized by the government that it can authorize a master's degree to the students.

> [碩士點](http://terms.naer.edu.tw/detail/1313197/?index=8)係指經授權後能自行授予碩士學位的學科或專業 **單位** （一般為 **學系** ）。

Answer (score 1):

点 here means "site". Like 网点。 They could have many sites or different kinds of sites, one of them is 光学硕士点.

Answer (score 1):

点 can means a location or place, example: 售后点